# Trying to find solution using SQL subquery in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, subquery

```
select ob_dt, count(*)
from table_name
group by ob_dt
order by ob_dt desc
```

I need to pick the `ob_dt` which has the highest count and need to do a select all for the `ob_dt` which has the highest count.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select ob_dt, count(*) as cnt
from table_name
group by ob_dt
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

To get the original data, you can use:

```
select t.*
from table_name t join
     (select ob_dt, count(*) as cnt
      from table_name
      group by ob_dt
      order by cnt desc
      limit 1
     ) d
     on t.ob_dt = d.ob_dt;
```

Comment: this will give me the ob_dt which has the max of row counts,, what i want is ...to pick this ob_dt which has the max of row count and do a select * from table_name

Comment: @SaraswathiJaikumar . . . .I was wondering if that was what you wanted.  I updated the answer.